# MS Release Management and Release Paths

Tags: continuous-integration, release, ms-release-management

I have started to dig in to Release Manager. Almost, if not all, examples I've seen uses a release path similar to Dev -> Test -> Production .

Say that I'm working with a web application and the organization is not using Continuous Integration in the real sense. Perhaps they are deploying to Dev many times per day, to Test a couple of times a week and to Production one time a month. (Dev and Test are then effectively different staging environments.)

So with a release path of Dev -> Test -> Production you will get a whole bunch of releases to Dev, but you don't want all Dev releases to go to Test. Therefore you would have to reject most of the releases until you are ready to deploy to Test.

What is the best practice here? Reject releases until you are ready to Test/Production? Create several Release Paths, such as:

- Dev
- Dev -> Test
- Dev -> Test -> Production

...or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a happy DevOps/continuous delivery world, the way it works is like this:

- You push bits to Dev as often as you want. The onus of picking a build to promote to QA is the developers' responsibility -- they should reject the releases they know won't be going anywhere. This is the post-deploy ("Validation") step in the Dev stage.
- QA schedules the release to their environment (pre-deploy, "Approval"). They test, and give it their blessing (post-deploy, "Validation"). They reject any releases that fail QA.
- Ops schedules the release to prod.

If this is an unlikely scenario because you know that none of your releases are production candidates up until a certain "blessed" build is created, then set your target stage for continuous delivery to "Dev" -- builds won't go beyond the dev environment. When you're ready to build something that's a QA and production candidate, build with a different target stage.

Comment: One more thing. You don't need to know if you will get to 'Prod' *before* the build. Even if your release starts with a Target Stage of 'Dev' and gets 'Released' after stage 'Dev', the Target Stage can than be modified to go further on the Release Path.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that you can specify the Target Stage. But you can only specify the Target Stage when you are triggering a release from within RM, correct? Triggering a resease from a build will always target the final stage in your configuration?

Comment: @Superhubert No, when you trigger the release from a build, you can specify the target stage. If you're using the Release Default Template, it should be an option.